# SSL certificate error from the website hosted in IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, azure-virtual-machine

I have two websites hosted on IIS on a Windows azure VM. Websites have individual FQDN with individual SSL certificates but same IP & Port.

"Require server name indication" is checked for second website.

Default Website domain - productname.companyname.com SSL Port 443
Second Website domain - secondproduct.companyname.com SSL Port 443

When I browse second website, I am getting server certificate invalid error & in browser it shows the SSL certificate of default website. SSL loads properly when browsed from inside the hosted server. I have the similar setup working in my non-prod environment but I'm not sure why it shows the SSL of default website.

I compared my configuration with non-prod environment where I am not getting any SSL certificate error.

Comment: So only in the production environment, site2 will show SSL certificate of default website. Certificate binding is fine so far, have you fully checked SNI and other configuration information? Perhaps you need to use the event viewer or through the FRT log to get more detailed error information.

Comment: Help yourself understand the settings at Windows HTTP API level, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background and then the culprit should be clear.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try to check FRT logs & post my findings

Comment: @LexLi Installed jexus manager on server & ran binding diagnostics. It only show "Found a conflicting TCP reserved port range. Please run "netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp" at command prompt to troubleshoot." not much helpful. Configured FRT log. status codes 403.1-999 but it's not logging anything when I try to browse. To confirm I tried to browse non existent page & it gave 404 & FRT was generated but not for SSL error.  Only difference that I can think of is my non prod SSL is a multidomain certificate which support dev.website.com, test.website.com etc

Comment: Reading the report/logs isn’t a trivial thing. If you don’t share them somewhere, no one is able to help much. Or you might want to open a support case with Microsoft, https://support.Microsoft.com

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background This section mentions "That’s why when we attempt to host multiple HTTPS sites on a single IP end point we could only use a wildcard certificate or a UC certificate." My non prod certificate is a multi domain certificate.  Subject Alternative Name (SAN) field on this certificate lists both the domains. While SAN is not present on the certificate I have for prod.

Comment: I repeated adding new website process on both non-prod & prod servers. So, that confirms I'm doing same thing for prod & non-prod. I tried to use my prod SSL certificate on non-prod server & it did give me certificate invalid error but loaded the prod SSL certificate not the SSL of default website